# How do I log onto my account

Tags: support

My question was transferred here from stackoverflow.  My visible name is Pete Alvin.  I tried logging in using Google Open ID and it can't find it.  So how in the world to I authenticate or claim Pete Alvin?

Comment: The weirdest thing is that serverfault.com "half" knows who I am... see it's using my picture from stackoverflow.com but I haven't logged into serverfault.com yet!

Comment: This question should be on meta - so you've got another site to go to :-).

Comment: See also [New Automatic Account Association](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/05/new-automatic-account-association/).

Answer (score 2):

If you use the same Open ID to create account at multiple sites, you should be told that the new account will be joined to the preexisting one. For example, I only had to enter my display name on the first site I registered on (this one).